# How to change swap area partition?

Tags: system, ssd, hdd, swap

I'm using Elementary on Lenovo S540 laptop, which has separate HDD and SSD. I've installed OS on the SSD and create a swap area. Can i delete this swap on SSD and create another on HDD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run Gparted and create a swap partition in the disk. Right click on that partition >>information tab.
There you locate UUID and location (ex. /dev/sda5). Then you open '/etc/fstab' (can be opened with Sketch or Sublime) and modify the lines `#swap was on <prev dev location>` and `UUID=<prev UUID>` to new data. Save it (you'll need admin password) and reboot your system. To delete previous swap partition boot any OS (not Windows) from USB or from another disk, run Gparted and delete previous swap partition.